# How to convert string to raw string in dart

Tags: dart

**I want to convert an existing string to raw string.**

**like:**

```
String s = "Hello \n World"
```

I want to convert this s variable to raw string(I want to print exact "Hello \n Wrold")

**I need backslash(\) in output. I am trying to fetch string value from rest api. it have bunch of mathjax(latex) formula containing backslash.**

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `String s = r"Hello \n World";` ?

Comment: Yes. ho to do that programmatically ?

Comment: So you gets a String from some REST API which contains e.g. the newline character and wants to convert it to the text "\n" instead?

Comment: The backslash should not influence the data you get from the REST API. It is only used when Dart compiles a String into a String object in code. So if you e.g. read a String from a file containing the letters "\n" it will not be seen as a newline character but instead as the letters "\n".

Comment: exactly, i get string containing backslash(\\). when i print it or show(in flutter_tex) backslash is omitted automatically.

Comment: thanks @julemand101. let me try again. If i overcome or fixed i will inform in comment box.

Comment: Converting a string to a raw string doesn't make sense. ("Raw string" means a string that exactly matches what you've typed in code.) What you want to do is to *escape* an existing string.  I've never used it, but it seems like [`package:strings` has an `escape` function](https://pub.dev/documentation/strings/latest/strings/escape.html) that could do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for a way to *escape* newlines (and possibly other control characters) in a string value.

There is no general way to do that for Dart strings in the platform libraries, but in most cases, using [`jsonEncode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html) is an adequate substitute.

So, given your `string` containing a newline, you can convert it to a string containing `\n` (a backslash and an `n`) as `var escapedString = jsonEncode(string);`. The result is also wrapped in double-quotes because it really is a JSON string literal. If you don't want that, you can drop the first and last character: `escapedString = escapedString.substring(1, escapedString.length - 1);`.

Alternatively, if you only care about newlines, you can just replace them yourself:

```dart
var myString = string.replaceAll("\n", r"\n");
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer save me a lot of time.