# How to print a character's representation instead of the symbol

Tags: flutter, dart

A quick example - I want to print "\n" instead of a new line character when I print a string. How do I achieve that?

But,
I want to be able to do this for any character. Example `\x80` is rendered as `€`, so how do I convert `€` to `\x80`?

I want to do this in Dart, but any language-independent way to achieve this is also appreciated.

EDIT 1: Incase its unclear, the string object is already in memory, I know I can escape the escape character using another `\`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string to raw string in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62270974/how-to-convert-string-to-raw-string-in-dart)

Answer (score 2):

Use `\\` to print backslash instead of special symbol. So `\\n` will print `\n` and `\\x80` will print `\x80`. It is correct for almost all languages that use escape sequences with starting `\`

UPD: If string is already in memory then it is up to you to write code to display escape sequences instead of special characters. Process every character of the string and print corresponding escape sequence.

Comment: You probably didn't understand the question correctly, the string object is already in memory.

Comment: @PrerakMann If string is already in memory then it is up to you to write code to display special characters.